# Allowing access to my server's ports when the server is connected to OpenVPN (Ubuntu Server 18.10)

Tags: server, vpn, iptables, openvpn, ufw

I've recently installed Ubuntu Server 18.10, and would like to open some ports (i.e. SSH, HTTP) to be accessible to the public. However, because of my ISP's constraints (my ISP is on a CGNAT and will not allow me to open ports), I'm connecting the Ubuntu server to a VPN that allows me to forward ports to my local machine via OpenVPN.

I am already able to connect properly to the OpenVPN server, and my VPN already allows port forwarding and has already forwarded the ports from the VPN. I can also ping the Ubuntu Server using my VPN's public IP address. However, I couldn't connect to my Ubuntu Server's ports (22/80) despite forwarding the ports on my VPN server.

Is there something I need to do on my Ubuntu Server to make it work? I'm trying to understand both iptables and ufw, and tried several topics around the Internet, but I couldn't seem to make it work. I'm not a network guy so I hope you could guide me how to set up ufw and/or iptables to allow my Ubuntu Server's ports to be accessible to my VPN's public IP.

Hope someone could help me out. Thanks!

Here's the output of my ufw status, iptables, and ifconfig for reference:

**ufw status**

```
$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

**iptables**

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-FIREWALL  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
KUBE-NODEPORT-NON-LOCAL  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* Ensure that non-local NodePort traffic can flow */
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
KUBE-FIREWALL  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain KUBE-FIREWALL (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes firewall for dropping marked packets */ mark match 0x8000/0x8000

Chain KUBE-NODEPORT-NON-LOCAL (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:netbios-ssn
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:microsoft-ds
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

**ifconfig**

```
$ sudo ifconfig
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:a9:b0:c9:f2  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.254  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fee1:76a8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:e1:76:a8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 86235  bytes 129085349 (129.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 21648  bytes 3799697 (3.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 20111  bytes 4496081 (4.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 20111  bytes 4496081 (4.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet xx.xx.xx.xx  netmask xx.xx.xx.xx  destination xx.xx.xx.xx
        inet6 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  prefixlen xx  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 85482  bytes 118463837 (118.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 21444  bytes 1207429 (1.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**netstat**

```
$ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         xx.xx.xx.xxx    128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ens33
xx.xx.xx.xx      192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 ens33
xx.xx.xx.xx    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U         0 0          0 tun0
128.0.0.0       xx.xx.xx.xx    128.0.0.0       UG        0 0          0 tun0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 docker0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 ens33
```

Comment: I will try to help you please paste the output of the following commands: sudo ufw status verbose sudo iptables -L sudo ifconfig Please do not paste the internet IP here :)

Comment: Thanks @Alpy. I'm updating my post so you can see the output

Comment: How your routing table looks like? Please update question with  `netstat -rn`

Comment: to eliminate any doubts please `sudo ufw disable ` and try again to access and after enabled it back `sudo ufw enable`

Comment: @Alpy, originally ufw is disabled, but it's no longer working back then. I enabled ufw and allowed ports 22 and 80 but to no avail.

Comment: @fugitive added netstat output on my post